# NestJs migration TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: typescript, nestjs, database-migration, mikro-orm

I'm trying to implement multitenancy in `NestJs` service (using `mikro-orm`), I have 2 abstract entities: `BaseEntity` which has id primary key only and `MultiTenantEntity` which extends BaseEntity and has rolation to `TanantEntity`.

`BaseEntity`:

```
@Entity({ abstract: true })
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;
}
```

`MultiTenantEntity`:

```
@Entity({ abstract: true })
export abstract class MultiTenantEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => TenantEntity)
  tenant: Ref<TenantEntity, 'id'>;

  constructor(tenant: TenantEntity) {
    super();
    this.tenant = ref(tenant);
  }
}
```

Also, I have `UserEntity` which should be multi tenant, so I'm extending it to `MultiTenantEntity`:

```
@Entity({ tableName: 'users' })
export class UserEntity extends MultiTenantEntity {
  @Property()
  email: string;

  @Property()
  firstName: string;

  @Property()
  lastName: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => RoleEntity)
  role: Ref<RoleEntity, 'id'>;

  constructor(role: RoleEntity, tenant: TenantEntity) {
    super(tenant);
    this.role = ref(role);
  }
}
```

And when I'm running the command `npx mikro-orm migration:create` it returns error output:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Development\<project>\libs\database-entities\src\lib\user\user.entity.ts:8:33)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
  at Module.m._compile (C:\Projects\Development\<project>\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
  at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Projects\Development\<project>\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Development\<project>\libs\database-entities\src\lib\database-entities.ts:3:1)
```

**Any ideas?**

P.S. `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Development\<project>\libs\database-entities\src\lib\user\user.entity.ts:8:33)` line 8 is `export class UserEntity extends MultiTenantEntity {`